# Use saved column names in a list as a filter iron python

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I am new to iron python. This is my first code. I need to create a list filter that contains all the column names of a table. If I select a particular column name, the name of the column has to be stored in a document property. Using that document property I will create some calculated columns.

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this requirement?

I am able to do some reading and save all the columns in a list but I don't know how to proceed further.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *

colNames = []
table = Document.Data.Tables['TableName']
for column in table.Columns:
    colNames.append(column.Name)
print(colNames)
```

Comment: Do you need Iron Python to do this? You could create a drop-down list in a text area linked to a document property. The list can enumerate all the columns in your chosen table without coding. The selected item on the drop-down is then stored in your document property

Comment: Thank you @Gaia Paolini. I got your expert suggestions. Grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in spotfire analyst itself. Instead of using iron python I used "insert input field" and created a column property and added the columns for filtering.

any other suggestions are welcome for me to learn.